# Phonegap/ios - Capture video not saving to iPhone camera roll

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

When taking a video in the app the video is not saved to camera roll.

I have set the flag saveToPhotoAlbum: true.

My code

```
            opt = {
                limit: 1,
                saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
                quality: 1
            };

            navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(
                that.captureVideoOnSuccess,
                that.onCaptureFail,
                opt
            );
```

A similar code works for getPicture with no problems

```
        navigator.camera.getPicture(
            that.uploadPhoto,
            that.onCaptureFail, {
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
                saveToPhotoAlbum: true
            }
        );
```

Any idea how to over come this? 
Any solution will be welcome - by config, js code, Objective-C

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution (based on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/245nKJoqqak)

In plugins/org.apache.cordova.media-capture/src/ios/CDVCapture.m

Method - (CDVPluginResult*)processVideo:(NSString*)moviePath forCallbackId:(NSString*)callbackId

Uncomment the lines under

> /* don't need, it should automatically get saved

I don't know why those line are comment out...