# How to save recorded video on iPhone using Cordova + Phonegap?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework, video-capture

I use this function to record video using Cordova + Phonegap :

```
$scope.captureVideo = function() {

var options = { limit: 1, duration: 5, saveToPhotoAlbum: true };

$cordovaCapture.captureVideo(options).then(function(videoData) {

  var i, path, len;
  for (i = 0, len = videoData.length; i < len; i += 1) {
    path = videoData[i].fullPath;

    ///*******************************************//
    // Here I need to save the video in gallery. ????
    //********************************************//
}

}, function(err) {  });
}
```

After the video is recorded I need to save it in gallery?

Comment: I believe this is what you are looking for: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719594/phonegap-ios-capture-video-not-saving-to-iphone-camera-roll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, this doesn't seem to be supported by the cordova capture plugin.
I did find this

```
// <!---
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
//-->
```

## com.gomoob.cordova.video-helper

This file has been truncated. 
show original: https://github.com/gomoob/cordova-plugin-video-helper/blob/master/doc/index.md